# Powershell reset all com+

Tags: powershell

I want to reset all com+ on all the servers I am looping through.  This is what I have so far

```
$servers = Get-Content "d:\scripts\servers.txt"
foreach ($servername in $servers)
{

$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$comAdmin.Connect($servername)
$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication(com+ app name goes here)
```

}

I want to shutdown all complus components without having to specify the name

Comment: Define "reset all com+".

Comment: You don't need a foreach loop here, just pass $servers directly to `Invoke-Command`

Comment: I want to shut down com+ components

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/questions/256403/administer-com-from-powershell

Comment: I want to shut down all complus without stating the name of each one individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COMAdmin:

```
$sb = {
    $admin = New-Object -Com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
    $apps = $admin.GetCollection("Applications")
    $apps.Populate()
    $apps | % {
        $component = $apps.GetCollection("Components", $_.Key)
        $component.Populate()
        $component | % {
            $admin.ShutdownApplication("$_.Name")
        } 
    }
}

$servers | % {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock $sb}
```

More info [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/256403/administer-com-from-powershell). I just compiled the logic of all of it.

Comment: Implementing this into my script and testing it this week.  I will let you know if it works and will mark it as my best answer if it works.  Thank you